# Counting additive decompositions of $32$ with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Does anyone know how to do this following question using a "change of variables"?

Q:Determine the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 32$ where $x_i ≥ -2, 1 ≤ i ≤ 4$.

So I've done these sort of questions where $x_i ≥ 1$ or $0$, but now that there is a negative number in the restriction I am not sure how to go about solving this.. My teacher gave us a hint and said to use a "change of variable" to solve this, but I have no idea how to do this. Can someone shed some light and show me how to deal with cases with negative restrictions?

Comment: set $f_i=x_i+2$, so that $f_i \ge 0, 1 \le i \le 4$

Comment: What is the logic behind doing that?

Comment: You know how to solve for $f_i \ge 1 or 0$, but $x_i \ge -2$, so replace with a variable that satisfies for the condition we want. Since, $x_i + 2 \ge 0$, if we let $f_i = x_i +2$, then $f_i \ge 0$.

Comment: I see, thanks and what if the constraints were x1, x2, x3 > 0, and  0 < x4 ≤ 25? I am mainly confused about the last restriction placed on x4

Comment: I am not sure. I'd proceed like this: since $x_4 \gt 0$ solve the equations as you normally would and then check if $x_4 \le 25$, if yes, you are done, if not it means the equations don't have a solution.

Comment: What do you want to reduce to? Variables $\ge 0$? Variables $\gt 0$? Since your official question is about $x\ge -2$, I cannot really write an answer for $x_1\gt 0$, $x_4\le 25$.

Comment: $$0\lt x_4\leq 25 \implies 0\leq x_{4}-1\leq 24$$ Now find the number of solutions with $y=x_{4}-1\gt 24$ similary as mentioned by  tpb261, then subtract from the number of **all solutions**.

Answer (score 3):

For each $i$, write $y_i=x_i+2$. Then, you have to find the number of solutions of
$$(y_1-2)+(y_2-2)+(y_3-2)+(y_4-2)=32$$
or
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=40$$
but now $y_i\geq 0$.

If you prefer that $y_i\geq 1$ instead of $y_i\geq 0$, the change would be $y_i=x_i+3$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Since this question appears frequently, we'll calculate a general case:
$${\large%
x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n} = S\,,\qquad x_{i} \geq 0}
$$

> The solution is given by:
>   \begin{align}
> {\cal N}_{n}\pars{S}&=
> \sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{x_{n} = 0}^{\infty}
> \delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots +x_{n},S}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots
> \sum_{x_{n} = 0}^{\infty}
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{-x_{1} - x_{2} - \cdots - x_{n} + S + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{S + 1}}
> \pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 - z}^{-n}\over z^{S + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}{-n \choose k}\
> \overbrace{\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{z^{k}\over z^{S + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ \delta_{kS}}}
> =\pars{-1}^{S}{-n \choose S}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{S}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{S}{n + S - 1 \choose S}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#44f}{\large{\cal N}_{n}\pars{S} = {n - 1 + S \choose n - 1}}\,,\qquad
n \geq 1\,,\quad S \geq 0
$$

> In the particular case $\ds{\quad n = 4\,,\quad x_{i} \geq - 2\,,\quad S = 32
> \quad}$ it's equivalent to
>   $$
> \pars{x_{1} + 2} + \pars{x_{2} + 2} +\pars{x_{3} + 2} +\pars{x_{4} + 2}=40
> $$ 
>   So, we have to calculate $\ds{{\cal N}_{4}\pars{40}}$:
>   $$\color{#c00000}{\large%
> {\cal N}_{4}\pars{40}} = {43 \choose 3}
> ={43 \times 42 \times 41 \over 3 \times 2} = \color{#c00000}{\large 12341}
> $$

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about a change of variables.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It's not so clear what does it means. I guess it suggests to write something likes $\large y_{i} = x_{i} + 2$ such that $\large y_{i} \geq 0$. Maybe...

Comment: OK, I see you got the correct result at the end. But really, one does not need to use contour integrals to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generating functions:

For each $x_i$ the generating function of the $x_i$ as integer greater or equal to $-2$ is $x^{-2}(1+x+x^2+...)$ therefore for the 4 variables you get the generating function $f(x)=x^{-8}\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=x^{-8}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}CC_4^kx^k$

Now to find the solution of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=32$ under the terms, you need to find $k$ s.t $x^{k-8} = x^{32}$ and the solution is given by this $k$ corresponding cofficient. Therefore you get that the solution is given by:

$CC^{40}_4 = $${40+4-1}\choose{40}$

Answer (score 0):

In this case just put $y_i=x_i+2$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, for which one has the condition $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=40$. I suppose you know that this number is
$$
  (-1)^{40}\binom{-4}{40} = \binom{40+4-1}{40}
  = \binom{43}3 = 12341.
$$